# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer> -KeyEvent

Tags: java, arraylist, awtrobot

I wrote code who will first "record" (add to arraylist some keyevent). Like I press A C D A, and after program by the for each will be press this keys. I try do it by arraylist, but it iisnt working, anyone can help me? 
I have "robot cannot be resolved" too.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> keys;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        keys.add(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B) {
        keys.add(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
        keys.add(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        keys.add(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    } 

    for (int x : keys) {
        robot.keyPress(keys);
    }

}
```

Comment: On "it iisnt working" - Can you be more specific? What are you observing? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @AndyThomas Sure, sorry i delete important line, now its correct. In the loop for i have error.

Comment: "I have error" is vague. What do you expect, and what do you observe?

Comment: The variable `robot` has not been defined in the code snippet. According to the error message it also has not been defined anywhere else.

Comment: Where have you declared `robot`, what type is `robot`? Have you instantiated `keys`?

Answer (score 0):

I think a few lines are missing from your code.
You are never instantiating keys or robot.

However from your comment it seems the problem is in the loop.
You are calling `robot.keyPress(keys);` with keys being the list of key, however since you are looping I'm guessing you want the robot to press ONE key on each iteration of the loop, so it probably should be `robot.keyPress(x);`

But without more information about your code, or the error message it's hard to say.